# Pointer move to lines and delete them in php , How i do it?

Tags: php, arrays, file, pointers, buffer

I have lines as

```
abc
def
ghi
jkl
mno
pqr
xyz
```

I want to take the first 4 lines and delete them ?

I am using the file

```
$datafile="/var/www/html/test/data/$data";
$fp = fopen($datafile,"r");
```

I am stuck here !! how do I move pointer , how to use array or any buffer ??

Comment: You can do that in two lines: `$lines = file($filename);
file_put_contents( $filename, array_splice( $lines, 4 ) );`

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = file("/var/www/html/test/data/$data");
$array = array_slice($array, 4);
```

Comment: I'd suggest to put the result of `array_slice` in another variable and save the renaming ones to the file again...

Comment: Depends on if saving them is required. `$name = "/var/www/html/test/data/$data"; file_put_contents($name, array_slice(file($name), 4));`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `file_get_contents()` to get the contents of the file and then convert it to an Array using `preg_split()`. Once you have an array of lines; simply use `array_slice()` to slice the Array from the Index you desire... *in your case, 4*. The Code below shows how...

```
<?php

    // THE TEXT FILE TO BE READ:
    $targetFile             = "/var/www/html/test/data/$data";

    // GET THE CONTENTS OF THE FILE & STORE IT IN A VARIABLE (IF IT EXISTS)
    $strFileContents        = null;
    if(file_exists($targetFile)){
        $strFileContents    = file_get_contents($targetFile);
    }

    // EVERY LINE IN A IS TERMINATED BY A NEW LINE CHARACTER.... WE KNOW THAT.
    // SO WE SPLIT THE CONTENTS OF THE FILE USING THIS KNOWLEDGE...
    if(!is_null($strFileContents)){
        $arrFileLines   = preg_split("#\n#", $strFileContents);

        // SELECT ALL ELEMENTS FROM THE 4TH ELEMENT TILL THE END
        $arrResultant   = array_slice($arrFileLines, 4);

        // CONVERT THE ARRAY BACK TO STRING...
        $strBuffer      = implode("\n", $arrResultant);

        // RE-SAVE THE FILE BACK...
        file_put_contents($targetFile, $strBuffer);
    }
```

> Or even much concisely;

```
<?php

    // THE TEXT FILE TO BE READ:
    $targetFile             = "/var/www/html/test/data/$data";
    if(file_exists($targetFile)){
        $arrFileLines       = file($targetFile);
        if(!empty($arrFileLines) && count($arrFileLines) > 4){
            // SELECT ALL ELEMENTS FROM THE 4TH ELEMENT TILL THE END
            $arrResultant   = array_slice($arrFileLines, 4);

            // CONVERT THE ARRAY BACK TO STRING...
            $strBuffer      = implode("", $arrResultant);

            // RE-SAVE THE FILE BACK...
            file_put_contents($targetFile, $strBuffer);

        }
    }
```

Cheers... and Good Luck ;-)